# Rename multiple files based on count

Tags: unix

Based on the count from some other file, I need to rename all the files extensions.

Ex: If the count is 10 and there are 5 files exists, I need to rename all the files as below.

```
from File_1.txt to File_11.txt, 
from File_2.txt to File_12.txt,
from File_3.txt to File_13.txt,
from File_4.txt to File_14.txt,
from File_5.txt to File_15.txt
```

Can I use one unix command to do this, appreciate your help on this.

Regards,
NPK

Answer (score 0):

With standard UNIX you'd need more than one command, e. g.

```
count=10
for file in File_*.txt
do  augend=`echo $file|sed 's/File_\(.*\).txt/\1/'`
    mv $file File_`expr $augend + $count`.txt
done
```

But if you have a system with this [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) available, you can

```
rename 's/File_(.*).txt/"File_".($1+$ENV{count}).".txt"/e' File_*.txt
```

(assuming `count` has been exported to the environment) or

```
rename 's/File_(.*).txt/"File_".($1+'$count').".txt"/e' File_*.txt
```

as well.